# How to decode cyrillic ajax string passed to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I will ask again something similarly with risk of my question begin closed(i cannot delete the old thread,because it might get me banned,it says)..So i need to decode an ajax string which i am passing from HTML form to ajax and on to PHP.When i write in English and check values which is passed it is all right:

[image: Example1]

But when i write some in cyrillic this 'thing' is sended to php (word is "ку",same as "ku" in english)

[image: Example 2]

I am trying to fix this problem from like 24 hours and read SO much information that i got overwhelmed and totally blocked.
So once again there is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")); 
 $("#food_search").keyup(function(event){
  var search_term =$(this).val();
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"http://test.com/bg/%D1%82%D1%8A%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8/",
 data:{'fsearch':search_term},
 success:function(res){
  $("#food_search_result").html(res);
  console.log(res);
 },
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
           alert(xhr.status);
           alert(xhr.responseText);
           alert(thrownError);
       }
});
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              HTML
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="fsearch" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<div id="food_search_result"></div>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------
                              PHP
----------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "gosho";
$password = "0!ijgls9df";
$databaseName = "dbName";
$connect = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
$fsearch="";

if(!empty($_POST['fsearch'])) {
$fsearch = $_POST['fsearch'];

$req = $connect->prepare("SELECT title FROM food_data_bg WHERE title LIKE ?");
$value = '%'.$fsearch.'%';
$req->bind_param('s', $value);
$req->execute();
$req->store_result();
$num_of_rows = $req->num_rows;
$req->bind_result($title);
if ($req->num_rows == 0){

echo 'Няма резултати';
}
else{
while($data=$req->fetch()){
   ?>
       <div class="search-result">
           <span class="result-title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
       </div>
       <?php
       }
var_dump($_POST['fsearch']);
$req->free_result();
    }
}
?>
```

So for short this is Search engine which must check on every key up if there is a match in database with the inputed text and display it if there is.
And my question is:

How to decode the ajax information sended to php to display cyrillic characters as usual and not like %D0%BA and so on..

If you guys need additional info,to help me feel free to ask.Thank you all <3

Comment: have you tried urldecode()?

Comment: And thats right there is the most confusing part to me.Some guys in this forum said that you must first encode in ajax than decode by php. Some says that PHP Post method decodes it automatically,some says that i need to add DataType as UTF-8 in my ajax and maaany more,thats why i decided to ask by myself.So please if you are know how this decode works and know where to paste it in my code and if i must edit my ajax,give some advices.Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess the problem wasn't totally clear for me,but i fixed the problem the day after i asked the question.Andrew's answer is really awesome for sumbit button,but for now i won't make any button SOOO i fixed the problem by adding a single line of right AFTER the $connect and the code is:

```
$connect->set_charset("utf8");
```

The problem wasn't with any deconing,encoding atleast for now i saw that when i type like "" or / php returns \"\" or soo think for future i will need an of your advices for decoding,encoding so thank you guys ! <3 Once again i solved the problem with your help

Answer (score 1):

If u wand send some data to server first of all u need `serialize` your data.

```js
var request;

$("#foo").submit(function(event) {

  // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
  event.preventDefault();

  // Abort any pending request
  if (request) {
    request.abort();
  }
  // setup some local variables
  var $form = $(this);

  // Let's select and cache all the fields
  var $inputs = $form.find("input");

  // Serialize the data in the form
  var serializedData = $form.serialize();

  // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
  // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
  // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
  $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

  // Fire off the request to /form.php
  request = $.ajax({
    url: "/form.php",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
  });

  // Callback handler that will be called on success
  request.done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // Log a message to the console
    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
  });

  // Callback handler that will be called on failure
  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Log the error to the console
    console.error(
      "The following error occurred: " +
      textStatus, errorThrown
    );
  });

  // Callback handler that will be called regardless
  // if the request failed or succeeded
  request.always(function() {
    // Reenable the inputs
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
  });

});
```

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="foo">
  <p>Търсене на храни: <input type="text" name="fsearch" id="food_search"></p>
</form>
<div id="food_search_result"></div>
```

**PHP (that is, form.php):**

```
$fsearch = isset($_POST['fsearch']) ? $_POST['fsearch'] : null;
```

And try add this code to html. [documentation about this](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_meta_charset.asp)

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: @TsvetomirovYordan ask if u have any quetions)